# OpenMP: templated custom reduction for container (Eigen type)

Tags: c++, templates, openmp

I want to define custom OpenMP reductions for types from the Eigen library, specifically matrices. I managed to define one for a specific type, i.e. a dynamically sized vector of `long int`s, but I'd much rather define them more generally. Is it possible to define templated reductions? Of course the following does not compile (`'#pragma' is not allowed here`):

```
template<typename Derived>
#pragma omp declare reduction(+ : Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> : std::transform( \
        omp_out.begin(), omp_out.end(), \
        omp_in.begin(), omp_out.begin(), \
        std::plus<Index>() \
    )) \
    initializer( omp_priv = decltype(omp_orig)::Zero( \
        omp_orig.rows(), omp_orig.cols() \
    ) )
```

(code snippet based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149981/11770674) to a previous question of mine)

Is there a way to define templated custom reductions or something that achieves the same goal?

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328087/openmp-reduction-with-template-type) btw. It's not the same, because it describes using a standard reduction in a templated function.

Comment: I far as I know, using templates in user-defined reduction operators is sadly not supported yet. The reason you have the error comes from the fact that the preprocessor analysis is performed *before* the template analysis in C++.

Comment: I thought ```#pragma``` is a compiler directive, despite the appearance of a preprocessor directive..?

Comment: `#pragma` directive are actually preprocessing directives. You can check that for example in the [C++11 specification draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section 16.6. Note that this is also true for older and newer version of C++ as well as in C. Future versions of OpenMP may address this issue. OpenMP 5.1 already does a small step forward by enabling users to specify OpenMP directives through C++ attributes (rather than preprocessor directives).